# Extract varest object from a list R

Tags: r

I´m trying to estimate a Vector Autoregressive Model (VAR) and make a sensitivity study (Figure 1 of this paper https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.32.3.113). In this type of models, each variable depends on lags of itself and the other variables (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression).

When I estimate for example a VAR(p) when p indicates the number of lags of the variables (suppose the simple case p=1), I got a varest object, then I can make an impulse-response analysis applying the `irf` function like this:

```
install.packages(c("vars","forecast","urca","plyr"))

library(vars)               ### Se cargan las librerías
library(forecast)
library(urca)
library(plyr)

x <- rnorm(50)    
y <- rnorm(50)    
z <- rnorm(50)

data <- cbind(x,y,z)

var1 <- VAR(data, p=1)    

irf1 <- irf(var1)    
plot(irf1)
```

I can apply the `irf` function to `var1` because `var1` is a varest object.

What I want is cutting the series and specifying differents VAR models (p=1,2,3,4,5), In the sense that I can apply the `irf` function for all the models.

What I did was create a list object and save all the models in `proof` like this:

```
n   = 25    
k   = 5    

proof = list()    

for(j in 1:k){
  for(i in 1:n){
    proof <- c(proof,VAR(cbind(x[i:50],y[i:50],z[i:50]),
                       p = j, type = c("none"),  season = NULL,  exogen = NULL))
  }
}
```

Now, proof is not is not a varest object, then I can not apply the `irf` function. What I tried was this:

```
for(j in 1:k){
  for(i in 1:n){
    proof <- c(proof, irf(VAR(cbind(x[i:50],y[i:50],z[i:50]),
                       p = j, type = c("none"),  season = NULL,  exogen = NULL)))
  }
}
```

So my questions: is there a way to extract the models from the list? or is there a way to save the impulse response function in another list.

Thanks and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Save the original results of `VAR` to `proof`, as in your first code chunk. Then do `lapply(proof, irf)` to create a new list of the results of `irf`. Also, please read [mcve] on how to create an example the rest of us can run!

Comment: But my second chunk of code doesn´t run becacuse I can not apply irf to a list object. Now my code run, sorry, I´m new.

Comment: That's why you do `lapply`, which applies a function to each element of a list in turn. So if you do `results <- lapply(proof, irf)` you will get the result of applying `irf()` to each member of the `proof` list.

Comment: The thing is I have to apply `irf` function to a `varest` object, but a `varest` object contains 10 lists, so `lapply` tries to apply `irf` to each one of these but not all the `varest` object.

Comment: Sure, but in your code above, `proof` is a list of `varest` models, not a `varest` model itself, right? That's what the line `proof <- c(proof, VAR(...))` does. Or am I missing something?

Comment: So to be clear: run your first chunk of code. Then, do not run your second chunk. Instead, just run `results <- lapply(proof, irf)`.